# How react can run in views folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have a `React` app in `views` folder. There is `Root Folder` contains `model` and `controller` and `views`. In that `views` folder. I have a `React app`. so, How can start both ??? Only I can run either `root folder` or `react`. Please help me. how to `folder structure`

Answer (score 0):

No problem with folder structure, you can stay with this structure.
You can use an npm package called [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).
This package will help you run your backend and frontend simultaneously.
Install this package on your root directory.
Like> `npm install concurrently --save`
then inside your root package.json file(i am assuming you using Nodejs as backend and have nodemon package installed)
use  this commmand on **scripts** > `"scripts": { "start": "node index", "server": "nodemon index", "client": "npm run start --prefix client", "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"cd views && npm start\"" },`
then from your root terminal type `npm run dev` .
Hope it will work.
If it didn't, then please stay with documentation of that [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

Comment: Just use a different port for backend than 3000, because react app uses it by default.

Comment: ok sir thank you sir for tried to help me. I will definetely try this solution and reach you back. By the way I change the node `port` to `8080`. and react is running on `port:3000`. its working fine . im getting the result. i will try your suggestion too